# groovy source install is strange

Tags: pcl, rosdep, build-from-source, opencv2, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,
I installed ROS at least 4 times from source on different devices over the last month. I still do not really understand the structure behind this procedure. Let's say I want to build the desktop package from source. I would have to initialize wstool using http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
Then I call rosdep to have all dependencies installed and call catkin_make after that. What I do not see is why OpenCV2 and PCL are downloaded into the src folder and compiled using catkin_make and are not installed with rosdep using prebuilt binaries. Especially when you build on embedded devices, those huge libraries consume a lot of time and space to compile. If there is a reason, please let me know

Kai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54089/groovy-source-install-is-strange/) by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source based installations are designed to support people running on platforms without prebuilt binaries available or who do not want to or cannot use the prebuilt binaries.

For example your use case on most embedded devices prebuilt binaries do not exist.

If you don't want to build something because you have resolved the dependency externally, you can just remove it from your workspace.  You will have to make sure that the external installation of the package is in your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-03**:
that is what my assumption was from the beginning. I got only confused because on MacOS rosdep also installs dependencies from source. I really like that approach because it will result in only ROS packages to be placed in the src folder. Couldn't PCL and OpenCV be installed the same way?